# How to get this desired output by joining two array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have two array of objects that has common key **pin** and an empty customer array. I'm trying to combine them as shown in expected output but couldn't figure out how to proceed. Can you please give me some pointers on how to achieve this?

I tried slicing the array2 data and then manually pushing data to array1 customer key but I'm getting duplicates. Please help me.

**Array1 data**

```
[
  { "id": 1, "email": "pwitterick0@uol.com.br", "pin": 600090, "customer": [] },
  { "id": 2, "email": "ssivorn1@pagesperso-orange.fr", "pin": 600090, "customer": [] },
  { "id": 3, "email": "nlawford2@usatoday.com", "pin": 600090, "customer": [] },
  { "id": 4, "email": "rclipsham3@vistaprint.com", "pin": 600090, "customer": []},
]
```

**Array2 data**

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "first_name": "Amble",
    "last_name": "Huntly",
    "email": "ahuntly0@symantec.com",
    "gender": "Male",
    "addr": "30 Badeau Circle",
    "pin": 600090
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "first_name": "Karlene",
    "last_name": "Forrest",
    "email": "kforrest1@rediff.com",
    "gender": "Female",
    "addr": "9417 Sutherland Avenue",
    "pin": 600090
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "first_name": "Mel",
    "last_name": "Kayley",
    "email": "mkayley2@xinhuanet.com",
    "gender": "Female",
    "addr": "7 Sage Crossing",
    "pin": 600090
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "first_name": "Nissa",
    "last_name": "Abelov",
    "email": "nabelov3@macromedia.com",
    "gender": "Female",
    "addr": "2906 Fairfield Circle",
    "pin": 600090
  },
  {
    "id": 5,
    "first_name": "Benn",
    "last_name": "Calbrathe",
    "email": "bcalbrathe4@amazon.de",
    "gender": "Bigender",
    "addr": "2914 Steensland Avenue",
    "pin": 600090
  },
  {
    "id": 6,
    "first_name": "Hobard",
    "last_name": "Toffanini",
    "email": "htoffanini5@simplemachines.org",
    "gender": "Genderfluid",
    "addr": "33695 Luster Street",
    "pin": 600090
  },
  {
    "id": 7,
    "first_name": "Jabez",
    "last_name": "Arlidge",
    "email": "jarlidge6@spotify.com",
    "gender": "Male",
    "addr": "1827 Harper Parkway",
    "pin": 600090
  },
  {
    "id": 8,
    "first_name": "Mitchel",
    "last_name": "Jessard",
    "email": "mjessard7@ask.com",
    "gender": "Male",
    "addr": "52 Fieldstone Pass",
    "pin": 600090
  },
  {
    "id": 9,
    "first_name": "Robbyn",
    "last_name": "Kenningley",
    "email": "rkenningley8@imdb.com",
    "gender": "Female",
    "addr": "44447 Golf Course Terrace",
    "pin": 600090
  },
  {
    "id": 10,
    "first_name": "Jaynell",
    "last_name": "todor",
    "email": "jtodor9@hexun.com",
    "gender": "Female",
    "addr": "3 Shoshone Junction",
    "pin": 600090
  },
]
```

I want the new array to have a length of **Array1 i.e., 4**. I just want to fill the **customer array in each object of Array1 with Array2 objects equally except the last one**.

So each customer gets **Math.round(Array2.length/Array1.length)** which is 2. I want each customer key in each object of array1 to be filled with 2 objects of array 2. Like shown below. Last dude gets assigned the remaining ojects as there are no more users in array1.

**Expected output**

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "email": "pwitterick0@uol.com.br",
    "pin": 600090,
    "customer": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "first_name": "Amble",
        "last_name": "Huntly",
        "email": "ahuntly0@symantec.com",
        "gender": "Male",
        "addr": "30 Badeau Circle",
        "pin": 600090
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "first_name": "Karlene",
        "last_name": "Forrest",
        "email": "kforrest1@rediff.com",
        "gender": "Female",
        "addr": "9417 Sutherland Avenue",
        "pin": 600090
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "email": "ssivorn1@pagesperso-orange.fr",
    "pin": 600090,
    "customer": [
      {
        "id": 3,
        "first_name": "Mel",
        "last_name": "Kayley",
        "email": "mkayley2@xinhuanet.com",
        "gender": "Female",
        "addr": "7 Sage Crossing",
        "pin": 600090
      },
      {
        "id": 4,
        "first_name": "Nissa",
        "last_name": "Abelov",
        "email": "nabelov3@macromedia.com",
        "gender": "Female",
        "addr": "2906 Fairfield Circle",
        "pin": 600090
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "email": "nlawford2@usatoday.com",
    "pin": 600090,
    "customer": [
      {
        "id": 5,
        "first_name": "Benn",
        "last_name": "Calbrathe",
        "email": "bcalbrathe4@amazon.de",
        "gender": "Bigender",
        "addr": "2914 Steensland Avenue",
        "pin": 600090
      },
      {
        "id": 6,
        "first_name": "Hobard",
        "last_name": "Toffanini",
        "email": "htoffanini5@simplemachines.org",
        "gender": "Genderfluid",
        "addr": "33695 Luster Street",
        "pin": 600090
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "email": "rclipsham3@vistaprint.com",
    "pin": 600090,
    "customer": [
      {
        "id": 7,
        "first_name": "Jabez",
        "last_name": "Arlidge",
        "email": "jarlidge6@spotify.com",
        "gender": "Male",
        "addr": "1827 Harper Parkway",
        "pin": 600090
      },
      {
        "id": 8,
        "first_name": "Mitchel",
        "last_name": "Jessard",
        "email": "mjessard7@ask.com",
        "gender": "Male",
        "addr": "52 Fieldstone Pass",
        "pin": 600090
      },
      {
        "id": 9,
        "first_name": "Robbyn",
        "last_name": "Kenningley",
        "email": "rkenningley8@imdb.com",
        "gender": "Female",
        "addr": "44447 Golf Course Terrace",
        "pin": 600090
      },
      {
        "id": 10,
        "first_name": "Jaynell",
        "last_name": "todor",
        "email": "jtodor9@hexun.com",
        "gender": "Female",
        "addr": "3 Shoshone Junction",
        "pin": 600090
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. You might find reading the site [help section](https://stackoverflow.com/help) useful when it comes to [asking a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and this [question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist). Code that you've worked on to solve the problem should include a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), and be included in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `for` loop and `splice()` for doing that

```js
const arr1 = [{
    id: 1,
    email: "pwitterick0@uol.com.br",
    pin: 600090,
    customer: []
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    email: "ssivorn1@pagesperso-orange.fr",
    pin: 600090,
    customer: []
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    email: "nlawford2@usatoday.com",
    pin: 600090,
    customer: []
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    email: "rclipsham3@vistaprint.com",
    pin: 600090,
    customer: []
  },
];
const arr2 = [{
    id: 1,
    first_name: "Amble",
    last_name: "Huntly",
    email: "ahuntly0@symantec.com",
    gender: "Male",
    addr: "30 Badeau Circle",
    pin: 600090,
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    first_name: "Karlene",
    last_name: "Forrest",
    email: "kforrest1@rediff.com",
    gender: "Female",
    addr: "9417 Sutherland Avenue",
    pin: 600090,
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    first_name: "Mel",
    last_name: "Kayley",
    email: "mkayley2@xinhuanet.com",
    gender: "Female",
    addr: "7 Sage Crossing",
    pin: 600090,
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    first_name: "Nissa",
    last_name: "Abelov",
    email: "nabelov3@macromedia.com",
    gender: "Female",
    addr: "2906 Fairfield Circle",
    pin: 600090,
  },
  {
    id: 5,
    first_name: "Benn",
    last_name: "Calbrathe",
    email: "bcalbrathe4@amazon.de",
    gender: "Bigender",
    addr: "2914 Steensland Avenue",
    pin: 600090,
  },
  {
    id: 6,
    first_name: "Hobard",
    last_name: "Toffanini",
    email: "htoffanini5@simplemachines.org",
    gender: "Genderfluid",
    addr: "33695 Luster Street",
    pin: 600090,
  },
  {
    id: 7,
    first_name: "Jabez",
    last_name: "Arlidge",
    email: "jarlidge6@spotify.com",
    gender: "Male",
    addr: "1827 Harper Parkway",
    pin: 600090,
  },
  {
    id: 8,
    first_name: "Mitchel",
    last_name: "Jessard",
    email: "mjessard7@ask.com",
    gender: "Male",
    addr: "52 Fieldstone Pass",
    pin: 600090,
  },
  {
    id: 9,
    first_name: "Robbyn",
    last_name: "Kenningley",
    email: "rkenningley8@imdb.com",
    gender: "Female",
    addr: "44447 Golf Course Terrace",
    pin: 600090,
  },
  {
    id: 10,
    first_name: "Jaynell",
    last_name: "todor",
    email: "jtodor9@hexun.com",
    gender: "Female",
    addr: "3 Shoshone Junction",
    pin: 600090,
  },
];

const count = Math.floor(arr2.length / arr1.length);

for (let i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++) {
  const remaining = arr2.length;
  if (i === arr1.length - 1) {
    arr1[i].customer.push(...arr2);
    break;
  }
  arr1[i].customer.push(...arr2.splice(0, count));
}
console.log(arr1);
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I need to look into this splice method.

Answer (score 0):

Let's define `arr1` as our first `array` and `arr2` as the second `array` :

```
let fillCustomers = function(arr1, arr2) {
    const customerPerArray = Math.floor(arr2.length / arr1.length);

    for(let el of arr1) {
        for(let i = 0; i < customerPerArray; ++i) {
            el.customer.push(arr2.shift());
        }
    }

    for(let i in arr2) {
        arr1[i].customer.push(arr2.shift());
    }

    return arr1;
}

let result = fillCustomers([...arr1], [...arr2]);
console.log(result);
```